# authenticate in network share (samba) without having to mount explicitly

Tags: mount, samba

I have this code in which I have to access a large number of dirs, some of them are network shares, looking for specific files.

In windows, I just do "net use //server/share /user:username password" and voilá! I can can go to the dir as if it was in my local machine.

How can I do the same in linux? I know that I can mount the share to a specific folder in my machine but that would imply managing a lot of dirs and I would really like to avoid that. Just like when I do it in windows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install smbfs:

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs
```

OR alternatively you can use cifs-utils:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Either will work, they are two different programs that implement windows shares. I've used smbfs successfully with the following steps, haven't tested it on cifs.

**If you only want a temporary mount,** for smbfs the command would be (all one line):

```
mount -t smbfs //server/share /mountdirectory -o username=share_user_name,password=share_password
```

Replace smbfs with cifs in this command if you've elected to use cifs-utils.

**If you want these shares to mount automatically on boot:**

Create a credentials file somewhere secure, name it `.smbcredentials`, and give it these contents:

```
username=share_username
password=share_password
```

To secure this file:

```
sudo chown root .smbcredentials
sudo chmod 600 .smbcredentials
```

Add this line to `/etc/fstab` (all on one line):

```
//server/share /mountdirectory smbfs credentials=/path/to/.smbcredentials,uid=USERSID,gid=USERSGROUPID 0 0
```

OR if using CIFS (again, all on one line):

```
//server/share /mnt/mountdirectory cifs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/whoever/.smbcredentials,dir_mode=0775,uid=USERID,gid=USERGROUPID 0 0
```

Here USERID is the id of the user that you want to have ownership of the mounted folder, and USERGROUPID is that users group id. Those can be found in /etc/passwd and /etc/group.

If you added one of those lines to your /etc/fstab file, you can now mount the share:

```
sudo mount -a
```

You should now see those shares mounted under the ownership of the local user and group you indicated in USERID and USERGROUP.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the detailed answer. Anyway i was asking for a way to do it without having to create a /mountdirectory .. Your solution means I'd have to create, manage and eventually delete several directores. What i want is to access a network folder and read its files without the need to create those auxiliar directories. Is that possível?

Comment: Yes, the answer instructs how to do so. See the command located under the heading "If you only want a temporary mount", that doesn't require the extra folder.

Comment: Hey, i have done this, but in my case i have to always to a manual `sudo mount -a` after each reboot. I think its a permissions thing.... @Dojo